# Why did laravel wrap my sidebar in an em tag?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

**Using Laravel 5.8.31 & Bootstrap 4. Browser: Chrome v. 76.0.3 and Opera 62.0.33 **

I was testing my CRUD functions by deleting a post. After deletion, the controller redirects back to my post index page. When the page loaded, the bootstrap side bar wrapped down below the other posts, rather than being on the right. Was fine before the post deletion.

I tried altering the cols and floating elements to no avail. Using Chrome dev tools, I see that the sidebar is nested in an em tag that isn't in the code. Tried clearing application cache. No effect.

I suspect this has something to do with the blade templating language and parsing the html, although if it is, I have no idea how to fix this other than manually installing the sidebar on every page.

How do I fix this??

Code can be found here: https://github.com/gkennedy87/Hillcrest/tree/master/resources/views

(It seems that laravel is also wrapping the footer in an em tag. Although this is a non-issue at the moment)

```
// views/posts/index.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')
      @section('content')
      @include('inc.navbar')

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

             <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
               <h1>Our Blog</h1>
               @if (count($posts) > 0)
                 @foreach ($posts as $post)
                   <div class="card mb-4">
                     <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/750x300" alt="Card image cap">
                     <div class="card-body">
                       <h2 class="card-title"><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
                       <p class="card-text">{!! str_limit($post->body,200,'...')!!}</p>
                       <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                       Posted on {{$post->created_at}} by
                       <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                @endforeach
             {{$posts->links()}}
             @else
             <p>No Posts Found</p>
           @endif
         </div>
       @include('inc.sidebar')

    <!--end row -->
</div>
    <!--end container -->
</div>
@include('inc.footer')
@endsection


// views/inc/sidebar.blade.php

<!--sidebar start -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="sticky">
            <!-- Search Widget -->
            <div class="card my-4">
              <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Categories Widget -->
            <div class="card my-4">
              <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">HTML</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Freebies</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">CSS</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Side Widget -->
            <div class="card my-4">
              <h5 class="card-header">Side Widget</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                You can put anything you want inside of these side widgets. They are easy to use, and feature the new Bootstrap 4 card containers!
              </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>

        <!-- sidebar end -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup the app on a local environment, the sidebar always stays on the right even after deleting a post. The response also doesn't contain any `em` tags. Could you try clearing the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look at the problem. I tried clearing the caches but it didn't fix the problem. Also cleared browser cache. This is really puzzling. In the code, you can see I used the @include blade directives for navbar, sidebar, and footer. In the browser, sidebar and footer are wrapped in these em tags, but not the navbar. I feel like the problem is here but not sure how to diagnose.

Comment: There aren't any `<em>` tags to be found? Could you add a screenshot of the sourcecode of the browser when loading the page? @gkennedy87

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/SMtDhm0.png Here is a link to the pic. I use the same sidebar and blade directive on single post views, but there is no problem there. It seems as tho, by deleting a post, the browser dynamically added the em tags in the DOM to the blog index page and that page only? @MaartenDev

Comment: does this happen in every browser? Could you try disabling plugins? @gkennedy87

Comment: I tested in Chrome, Opera, and Safari. Disabled plugins and tested again. No change. HOWEVER, I just tried to replicate the problem by deleting another post and suddenly the sidebar is fixed. My alert messages aren’t showing however, so perhaps it’s related to my alerts? @MaartenDev